# JS: how to access the variable declared in one JS file in another JS file

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the ***first.js*** file where I declared and initialized the array with valid value.

```
var arrVar = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
```

I want to use this variable "arrVar" in ***second.js*** file. How can I acheive this?

I tried adding below statment in the second.js file at the beginning.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/first.js"></script>
```

But I am getting error "Unexpected Token <"

Answer (score 3):

You can't add HTML tags into JavaScript files.

And as long as `arrVar` has been defined in the global scope (not inside any function), it should be accessible in any other file, as it is a global variable.